# iTunes says I can't back up iPhone because I don't have enough space...but I do

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup

I'm trying to move my iphone data from my old iPhone 5 to an iPhone 6s. To start, I'm trying to back up my iPhone 5 to my Windows 7 computer running iTunes. It connects, starts the backup, but about 15 minutes into it I get a message saying there's not enough space on the computer to do the backup.

I have 582GB free on that drive (It's backing up to the C: drive).

So, needless to say, I'm confused. I've found a few articles that talk about issues with iCloud and wireless backing up, but this is connected direction to my PC so I don't think that's the issue.

The official Apple documentation says to "free up space" which isn't the issue, or contact support. So, no real help there, either.

Answer (score 2):

So after much swearing and several hours of fiddling, I finally discovered what the issue was.

Windows appears to have a limit on how many files can exist in a directory tree. iOS backups consist of tens of thousands of individual files. And if you have several backups in your backup folder, we're talking a whole lot of files.

The solution ended up being fairly simple:

- find your backup folder on your hard drive
- move most (or all) of the backups that are in that folder to a separate folder and/or drive.

Then try backing up again. For me, that solved it and I was able to get the backup to run.

Answer (score 0):

You've addressed this, but I want to make sure I double-check: Did you make any windows junctions in the past to map your user account data folder (or the iTunes backup folder) to another drive other than that primary c: drive?

Assuming not, here is what I would try first:

1. Go in and rename or delete the folder for the previous backup for this device (the one named with the device UDID)
2. If that doesn't help, then rename the `Backup` folder inside of MobileSync, and then make an entirely new `Backup` folder.

There's instructions for each of these on an old blog post of mine (under "iPhone Disconnected Error During a Backup") https://deciphertools.com/blog/2014_12_09_iphone_could_not_restore_disconnected/

Comment: Thanks, Kelly. I actually did figure out the isse. Will post an answer!